# JavaScript date error (incorrect month)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, date

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date(2017,06,10,11,33,30,0);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the  above code.It  says that

Mon Jul 10 2017 11:33:30 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)

But today is a saturday.
But it shows Mon.
.Is this a bug in Javascript
?

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript to avoid collision with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a month is counting from 0 to 11. Compare it with Date now:

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date(2017,5,10,11,33,30,0);
var c = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = c;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks dude.I missed that

Answer (score 0):

In js the month start from 0 to 11 where 0 is January and 11 is December. So here `06` is the month of July but not June

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!.I missed that completely.Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

month starts from 0

```
var d = new Date(2017,05,10,11,33,30,0);
```

will yield 
Sat Jun 10 2017 11:33:30 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: Thanks for the help.I missed that